# Downloading a file using AJAX in an EXT.JS blind

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I've got the following ajax call:

```
var blind = Ext.create('MyApp.view.blind.Progress', {});
         blind.show();
         Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: config.url,
            params: {
               nodeId: config.data[0].value,
               fileName: config.data[1].value,
               startDateTime: config.data[2].value,
               endDateTime: config.data[3].value,
               reportFormat: config.data[4].value
            },
            success: function (response) {
               console.log(response);
               blind.close();
            }
         });
```

I want to display a blind with a loading graphic, and close it upon completion. Is there any way to use this ajax callback to download the file from the response? Am I on the right track? I would like to avoid using iframes or opening new tabs if possible. I'm open to using other libraries like jquery if it's easier.

Comment: You cannot really track when the download finish. You would need a parallel Ajax request to the same server to archive this. This request can the also return how much data has been stream. The request would poll (with a task) every 1 or 2 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't like being told what I can't do so I kept researching and found this jquery plugin. It works by polling a cookie made by the server when the file is delivered, and the typical iframe method for downloading files. No bloat, no flash, exactly what I was looking for:

[Jquery File Download](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)

Download the plugin, link it somewhere in your site, and add this cookie generation code to wherever your file request is going (there are more examples at the link, I'm using ASP.NET):

`HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true") { Path = "/" });`

Sample code from my app, using the success and fail callbacks of the plugin to control my extjs blind:

```
$.fileDownload(config.url, {
     successCallback: function (url) {
        //Show a message here or perform some task
        blind.close();
     },
     failCallback: function (html, url) {
        blind.close();
        alert("The report generation failed.");
     },
     httpMethod: "POST",
     data: {
        nodeId: config.data[0].value,
        fileName: config.data[1].value,
        startDateTime: config.data[2].value,
        endDateTime: config.data[3].value,
        reportFormat: config.data[4].value
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think its possible to respond with a file to an ajax request. a simple form submit should do the trick.

Comment: @Gallen dbrin is right, it is Definitive not possible to do this with a Ajax request.